# Cant start geany debugger

Tags: geany

I've installed geany 1.32 and also installed plugins using

```
sudo apt-get install geany-plugins
```

And it worked for me but when I start geany and open plugin manager I cant see the debugger plugin.
[image]

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using, and how did you install geany 1.32 (also using `apt-get`, or by some other means?)

Comment: 16.04.1-Ubuntu.   
Installed geany by downloading the package, compiling and installing it manually.

Answer (score 0):

If you compiled and installed Geany from source, you also need to download the corresponding geany-plugins version and compile and install that one. The version of geany-plugins from apt-get might differ from the one you compiled and that could be why you don't see all plugins.

https://plugins.geany.org/geany-plugins/